# Action dispatched for one reducer is executing another reducer?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

If I call the action for `getList reducer`, it's getting dispatched to both `getList reducer(correct)` and `getUser reducer(incorrect)`.

Has anyone come across this type of error?

Comment: Putting in a skeleton code without much details would be helpful. May be you are not breaking after the first reducer is called.

Comment: @PraveenB Fixed brother, By default I didn't return state. This was the issue. Which caused unwanted updates in my store :/

Answer (score 0):

[Actions are not specific to a single reducer](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#is-there-always-a-one-to-one-mapping-between-reducers-and-actions).  There might only be one reducer that actually cares about a given action, but if you're using `combineReducers()`, [all slice reducers will be called and given a chance to respond to each dispatched action](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers).